3d plot в qt c++
решил задачу water among cubes на spoj
(https://www.spoj.com/problems/WATER/)
Сейчас хочу сделать gui в qt 
Как реализовать подобное отображение?
По сути, нужно повернуть плоскость (как бы странно не звучало)

Зачем вам именно такая картинка? Если для нужд отладки - скопируйте данные в excel и постройте график в нем. Освоение QWT, или любого другого способа строить графики в Qt - сложнее, чем исходная задача spoj.
